# Jquery extract string from url and load remote element

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm new in Jquery, I would like to have Jquery code to get the current page url and if the url contains certain string then load remote element.

example:

i have the page urls like this:

```
"http://......./Country/AU/result-search-to-buy"
"http://......./Country/CA/result-search-to-buy"
"http://......./Country/UK/result-search-to-buy"
```

the part "/Country/AU" is what I need to determine which page element I should load in, then if "AU" I load from "/state-loader.html .state-AU", if "CA" I load from "/state-loader.html .state-CA"

I have a builtin module "**{module_pageaddress}**" to get the value of the current page url, I just dont know the Jquery logic to let it work.

I expect something like this:

```
if {module_pageaddress} contains "/Country/AU/" 
$('#MyDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-AU');

if {module_pageaddress} contains "/Country/CA/" 
$('#MyDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-CA');
```

Comment: have you tried using the `.test()` method provided by the `JavaScript RegExp` object to test the string for that occurence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following if the country string is always last before the last slash in the URL

See a live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdHvh/)

```
var url = "http://......./Country/AU/result-search-to-buy"
var loc = url.split( '/' );

    //should be using the next line in live
//var loc = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

var country = alert(loc [loc.length-2]);
```